# (real analysis) Does this proof have an error?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

The problem is this.

$prove\ f(\bigcap_\alpha E_\alpha)=\bigcap_\alpha f(E_\alpha)$

So I tried it below.

$(1)\ f(\bigcap_\alpha E_\alpha)\subset \bigcap_\alpha f(E_\alpha)$

Suppose $y\in f(\bigcap_\alpha E_\alpha)$

$\Rightarrow \exists x\in \bigcap_\alpha E_\alpha\ s.t. y=f(x) \ for \ all\ a$

$\Rightarrow \exists x\in E_\alpha\ s.t. y=f(x)\ for\ all\ a$

$\Rightarrow \exists x\in E_\alpha\ s.t. y\in f(x)\ for\ all\ a$

$\Rightarrow y\in f(E_\alpha)\ for\ all\ a$

$\Rightarrow y \in \bigcap_\alpha f(E_\alpha)$

$(2)\ \bigcap_\alpha f(E_\alpha)\subset f(\bigcap_\alpha E_\alpha)$

Suppose $y \in \bigcap_\alpha f(E_\alpha) \Rightarrow y \in f(E_\alpha)\ for\ all\ a$

$\Rightarrow \exists x\in E_\alpha\ s.t. y=f(x) \ for \ all\ a$

$\Rightarrow \exists x\in E_\alpha\ s.t. y \in f(x)\ for\ all\ a$

$\Rightarrow \exists x\in \bigcap_\alpha E_\alpha\ s.t. y\in f(x)\ for\ all\ a$

$\Rightarrow y\in f(\bigcap_\alpha E_\alpha)$

Is there any error?

Comment: Why $y=f(x)$ for all $a$ implies $y\in f(x)$ for all $a$?

Comment: @HanulJeon Frankly, that's the logic what I'm wondering if it's right..

Comment: It does not hold in general. In fact, the equality $f(\bigcap_\alpha E_\alpha)=\bigcap_\alpha f(E_\alpha)$ does not hold unless $f$ is one-to-one.

Comment: @HanulJeon then if $f$ is one-to-one, $y=f(x) for\ all\ a$ can be replaced with $y \in f(x) for\ all\ a$?

Comment: No, this proof still does not work. We need a new proof for $\supseteq$, although your proof for $\subseteq$ is fine.

Comment: Define $f(x) = 0$ and let $E_k = \{k\}$. Then $E_1 \cap E_2 = \emptyset$ but $f(E_1) \cap f(E_2) = \{0 \}$.

Comment: @copper.hat why did you define $f$ and $E_k$ like that?

Comment: @HanulJeon new proof for ⊇? What do you mean?

Comment: @PhilliP Your proof for $f(\bigcap_\alpha E_\alpha)\supseteq \bigcap_\alpha f(E_\alpha)$ does not work even if $f$ is one-to-one, so we need another proof.

Comment: @HanulJeon but ⊆ is fine? I can't understand why ⊇ does not work because I used the same method.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you are right. This proof also does not work as you employed the same argument.

Comment: @PhilliP: Just giving a simple counterexample to your claim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof does not work, as we cannot conclude $y\in f(x)$ from $y=f(x)$.

Here is a correct proof: Let $x\in \bigcap_\alpha E_\alpha$, then $x\in E_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$. Therefore, $f(x)\in f(E_\alpha)$ for all $\alpha$, and we have $f(x)\in \bigcap_\alpha f(E_\alpha)$. By the definition of image under $f$, we have $f(\bigcap_\alpha E_\alpha)\subseteq\bigcap_\alpha f(E_\alpha)$.

The reverse inclusion does not hold in general (A counterexample by copper.hat works.) If $f$ is one-to-one, however, we can show the reverse inclusion:

Let $f$ be one-to-one and $y\in \bigcap_\alpha f(E_\alpha)$. For $\alpha\neq \beta$, we have $x\in E_\alpha$ and $z\in E_\beta$ such that $f(x)=y=f(z)$. Then $x=z$ as $f$ is one-to-one, so $x\in E_\beta$. Since $\beta$ is arbitrary, we can conclude that $x\in\bigcap_\alpha E_\alpha$ and $y=f(x)\in f(\bigcap_\alpha E_\alpha).$

Comment: I understand! Thx a lot!